# How to find route of a current page?

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a line of code that I can use in the controller that determines the route of a current page?

For example, I would like to find the route of the page with SEO url `https://example.com/desktops` (this should return the route `product/category`).

Similarly, url such as `https://example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=18&product_id=47` should return route as `product/product`.

Answer (score 16):

Right answer is `$this->request->get['route'];`.

In order to catch the current route, you can use `$this->request->get['route'];` in the `index()` function of the `catalog/controller/common/header.php` file. The `header.php` file is a part of practically any frontend output (as I understand, right now you are not sure what controller is used in the `http://example.com/desktops` URL, so you need right place where you can run your code in any case).

The SEO module does not unset this part of the **request object**. Also, keep in mind, in the middle of OpenCart code generation the `$_GET` array and the `$this->request->get` array are not the same things. You won't catch current route (in "path/controller/action" format) in the `$_GET` superglobal PHP's array when SEO module is in action, but you can catch it in any controller by using a `$this->request->get` array which is prepared for you by OpenCart engine.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by querying the `url_alias` table for the specific keyword to give you one of the four ID's that come with the standard setup (`product_id`, `category_id`, `information_id` and `manufacturer_id`) along with it's id value separated by an `=`.

In your desktops example, it would be something like `category_id=20`. From there, you need to work out the route

You can find the exact way OpenCart does this in the file `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

In controller we have `$this->request->get['route']`.

seo_url.php:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
}
```

Comment: @Jay Gilford, it was a mistake. I mean `_route_`. I see this key in my var_export($_REQUEST); in my index.php

Comment: `_route_` will give you they keyword, however this still doesn't provide the actual route

Comment: In controller there is `$this->request->get['route']` that contain what we want. Is not it?

Comment: Only if the SEO URL controller has already figured it out from the keyword

Comment: @Jay Gilford, Can you give an example where this is not happening? I want to understand where I'm wrong