# How to get the current url in a OpenCart .tpl file?

Tags: php, opencart

I'd like to get the current url in a .tpl file in OpenCart.

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321029/how-to-find-route-of-a-current-page) but it works only in a php file.

I have to get this way:

```
_my_array.push(['_productName',"<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"]);
**_my_array.push(['_productUrl', ["how can I get url ?"]]);**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get full url

```
<?php
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
```

and btw those answers work on tpl files also because tpl files are sort of php files only

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to get it in the controller then use it in the view file.

In your controller

`$data['current'] = $this->url->link($this->request->get['route'], '', 'SSL');`

Then in the view file

`echo $current;`

Comment: Make sure to replace `''` with `'token='.$this->session->data['token']` if you need an admin URL

Answer (score 0):

I also needed current url for schema.org.

Generally you can create current url via link function

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false)
```

So https link for product page that would be

```
$data['share'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . (int)$this->request->get['product_id'], true);
```

Then in the view file

`echo $share`